# Polymer 1.0 strategies for caching JSON data

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm working my way through learning about Polymer.  My objective is to create an element that's completely self-contained (routing within the app, managing data needs of the different sub-elements within the app).  My objective is to create a single element that users could inject into existing websites.  For example:

```
<my-app key="XXXXXXXXXX"></my-app>
```

'my-app' gets injected into existing sites.  The value of key is used with internal web-api calls for retrieving data specific to this implementation.

The internal structure of 'my-app' could be something like this:

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
     <template>
          <game-list></game-list>
          <game-detail></game-detail>
          <play-game></play-game>
          <leader-board></leader-board>
     </template>
</dom-module>
```

'game-list' provides a list of possible games a user could play.  The content here is dependent upon the value of 'key' property.  Likewise, 'game-detail' would be the detail of the game selected from 'game-list'.  'play-game' is the UI for allowing the user to play their selected game.  Finally, 'leader-board' shows rankings of all players using this app.

I need some help on strategies for managing json-data needs for each sub-element please.

1. What are best practices for caching a list of games retrieved for the 'game-list' element?  If a user navigates from 'game-list' to 'game-detail' then back to 'game-list', I do not want to make a subsequent call to web service to retrieve a list of games.
2. Navigating from 'game-list' to 'game-detail' will update the URL with the 'id' of the selected game (route:  '/game-detail/23').  I want to be able to cahce the game detail for the call with Id of 23.  So, if they come back to '/game-detail/23' again, then a call to WebAPI is not made.  However, if they navigate to '/game-detail/326', the app realizes 326 is different from 23 so it makes a new call to WebApi.

To summarize, what are strategies/best-practices for caching data?

I do a lot of AngularJS development and use Angular's services (they are singletons) to cache data for the UI.  Is there a way to do something similar with Polymer elements?  Is there a way to create an internal mechanism that acts as a data store?

I suppose I could rely upon local-storage, but would prefer some type of 'service' that acts as a resource that all elements can tap into to retrieve their data.  This 'service' would be the thing responsible for sending requests to WebAPI (via iron-ajax) and caching data as needed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one app, I used `iron-localstorage` to cache the backend data.

You can create your own `backend-element` that wraps a `iron-localstorage` and handles the caching transparently for all your elements.

Also you can check out [iron-meta](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-meta) which uses a monostate pattern to share data across different components.